# F# JSON Typeprovider crashes on missing data

Tags: f#, f#-data

How can I handle missing data in a JSON file? With lists of data you can simply use a map function. But what about an object

Say I have sample data:

```
{
    "Person":{
    "FirstName":"John",
    "LastName":"Doe",
    "Age": 42,
    "Address": {
        "Street": "SomeStreet",
        "City" : "Some City"
        }
    }
}
```

And my actual data comes in like:

```
{
    "Person":{
    "FirstName":"John",
    "Age": 42
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to make the address optional:

```
type personJson = JsonProvider<"Data/personSample.json">
let personData = testJson.Load("Data/personData.json")

let address = personData.Person.Addres // gives an exception
```

Also trying to convert it to an optional fails
    let p = personData.Person.Address |> Option.ofObj

System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier error
 The type 'JsonProvider<...>.Address' does not have 'null' as a proper value at 2,35

I can't imagine I should change the code for each file with some missing data.

So what should I do to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data sample for JSON type provider with optional property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978716/data-sample-for-json-type-provider-with-optional-property)

Comment: The short answer is you set `SampleIsList` to `true` and give a list of json objects of all possible shapes.

Comment: I have the impression that the SampleIsList doesn't work in my case. As mentioned in my question, I don't work with a list, but just with 1 object. After adding the SampleIsList, requesting the Address object still results in the exception: System.Exception: Property 'Address' not found at '/Person': {"FirstName":"John","Age":42,"Address":null}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SampleIsList = true` when setting up your type provider to offer multiple variations on how your objects are shaped.

```fs
open FSharp.Data

type personJson = JsonProvider<"Data/personsSample.json", SampleIsList = true>

let personData = personJson.Load("Data/personData.json")
```

The contents of `personsSample.json` could look like this, which includes both your original json and a variation of that json without an address:

```json
[
    {
        "Person":{
            "FirstName":"John",
            "LastName":"Doe",
            "Age": 42,
            "Address": {
                "Street": "SomeStreet",
                "City" : "Some City"
                }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "Person":{
            "FirstName":"John",
            "LastName":"Doe",
            "Age": 42
        }
    } 
]
```

Now when you load a single personData example, referencing the address field will handle a null value correctly instead of crashing.

Comment: I didn't know I could add multiple objects in my test set (one with address and one without). Now I get an  val it : Option<JsonProvider<...>.Address> = None -> So I can check my data without an exception. Thanks a lot Chad Gilbert!